# Can we form any circuit using half adders only? (assuming we have as many half adders as we want)

Tags: adder

Using various combinations on half adders I get these outputs:

```
{0,1,1,0},{0,0,0,1},{0,0,0,0},{0,1,1,1}
```

And I also know that we can form any gets using NAND gates or AND and NOT gates but I am not getting any output of the form  NOT so should I assume that we can't form universal gates using half adders?

Comment: _Any_ circuit only using half adders?

Comment: *I am not getting any output of the form NOT*. I am!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can, but why would you want to?

A NAND gate is a universal gate, as you have agreed. Here's how to form a NAND gate using a Half Adder:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6U0we.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That said, a NAND gate is the simplest two input gate you can form, at least in NMOS/CMOS, so it seems like a rather backwards step...

Comment: One possible answer for "why?" might be regularity and simplicity in an FPGA, if either (a) you tweaked the hell out of a half adder and replicated a million of them, or (b) your FPGA was mainly intended for arithmetic with only a few % of control logic, or both. But FPGAs are heading away from fine grained basic blocks because routing space...